# Spring Boot OAuth sample is not authenticating

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-boot, spring-cloud

I am trying to learn how to set up OAuth2 with Spring Boot and Spring Cloud by following [the instructions in this link](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-security-and-angular-js/#_sso_with_oauth2_angular_js_and_spring_security_part_v), which is part 5 of a larger tutorial.  After reading the tutorial several times and going step by step through it, I decided to study it again by simply downloading [the completed version from github at this link](https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-spring-security-and-angular-js/tree/master/oauth2).

The `authserver`, `resource`, and `ui` apps launch, but when I try to login, the authorization app does not accept the credentials given in the tutorial.  I would like to get the example working as intended on my devbox before decomposing it and testing the effects of small changes.

The specific line in the debug logs that states the error sent by Spring to the view is:

```
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : 
/login?error reached end of additional filter chain;   
proceeding with original chain
```

**What specific steps need to be taken in order to 1.) download and install the apps and 2.) login successfully using the authentication server?**

Here is what I have done so far:

On my CentOS 7 devbox terminal, I typed:

```
cd /home/user/spring_boot_apps/
mkdir whole_security_tutorial && cd whole_security_tutorial
git clone https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-spring-security-and-angular-js
cd /home/user/spring_boot_apps/whole_security_tutorial/tut-spring-security-and-angular-js/oauth2/authserver
mvn spring-boot:run
cd /home/user/spring_boot_apps/whole_security_tutorial/tut-spring-security-and-angular-js/oauth2/resource
mvn spring-boot:run
cd /home/user/spring_boot_apps/whole_security_tutorial/tut-spring-security-and-angular-js/oauth2/ui
mvn spring-boot:run
```

Then, in FireFox, I typed `http://localhost:8080`.  This caused a page to load that included the home and login links that are intended, so I clicked on the login link, which redirected to the authorization app, which displayed a login page.

I typed in `acme` as the username and `acmesecret` as the password, but the authentication failed with the message `There was a problem logging in.  Please try again.`

**What am I doing wrong?**

Note: I did not launch the app at `/home/user/spring_boot_apps/whole_security_tutorial/tut-spring-security-and-angular-js/oauth2` because doing so in a prior attempt failed to give access to the other child apps while also causing the other apps to fail to launch due to `port 9000` already being in use errors.

The Spring Boot debug log for the login attempt is as follows:

```
2016-04-11 01:56:10.805 DEBUG 17850 --- [nio-9999-exec-7] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/css/**']
2016-04-11 01:56:10.805 DEBUG 17850 --- [nio-9999-exec-7] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/login'; against '/css/**'
2016-04-11 01:56:10.805 DEBUG 17850 --- [nio-9999-exec-7] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/js/**']
2016-04-11 01:56:10.805 DEBUG 17850 --- [nio-9999-exec-7] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/login'; against '/js/**'
2016-04-11 01:56:10.805 DEBUG 17850 --- [nio-9999-exec-7] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/images/**']
2016-04-11 01:56:10.805 DEBUG 17850 --- [nio-9999-exec-7] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/login'; against '/images/**'
2016-04-11 01:56:10.805 DEBUG 17850 --- [nio-9999-exec-7] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/**/favicon.ico']
2016-04-11 01:56:10.805 DEBUG 17850 --- [nio-9999-exec-7] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/login'; against '/**/favicon.ico'
2016-04-11 01:56:10.805 DEBUG 17850 --- [nio-9999-exec-7] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/error']
2016-04-11 01:56:10.805 DEBUG 17850 --- [nio-9999-exec-7] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/login'; against '/error'
2016-04-11 01:56:10.805 DEBUG 17850 --- [nio-9999-exec-7] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : No matches found
2016-04-11 01:56:10.805 DEBUG 17850 --- [nio-9999-exec-7] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/login']
2016-04-11 01:56:10.805 DEBUG 17850 --- [nio-9999-exec-7] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/login'; against '/login'
2016-04-11 01:56:10.805 DEBUG 17850 --- [nio-9999-exec-7] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : matched
2016-04-11 01:56:10.805 DEBUG 17850 --- [nio-9999-exec-7] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /login at position 1 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
2016-04-11 01:56:10.805 DEBUG 17850 --- [nio-9999-exec-7] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /login at position 2 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
2016-04-11 01:56:10.805 DEBUG 17850 --- [nio-9999-exec-7] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : HttpSession returned null object for SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT
2016-04-11 01:56:10.805 DEBUG 17850 --- [nio-9999-exec-7] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade@2f575638. A new one will be created.
2016-04-11 01:56:10.805 DEBUG 17850 --- [nio-9999-exec-7] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /login at position 3 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
2016-04-11 01:56:10.805 DEBUG 17850 --- [nio-9999-exec-7] o.s.s.w.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter  : Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@63eea474
2016-04-11 01:56:10.805 DEBUG 17850 --- [nio-9999-exec-7] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /login at position 4 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'CsrfFilter'
2016-04-11 01:56:10.805 DEBUG 17850 --- [nio-9999-exec-7] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /login at position 5 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
2016-04-11 01:56:10.805 DEBUG 17850 --- [nio-9999-exec-7] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/login'; against '/logout'
2016-04-11 01:56:10.805 DEBUG 17850 --- [nio-9999-exec-7] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /login at position 6 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter'
2016-04-11 01:56:10.806 DEBUG 17850 --- [nio-9999-exec-7] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/login'; against '/login'
2016-04-11 01:56:10.806 DEBUG 17850 --- [nio-9999-exec-7] w.a.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter : Request is to process authentication
2016-04-11 01:56:10.806 DEBUG 17850 --- [nio-9999-exec-7] o.s.s.authentication.ProviderManager     : Authentication attempt using org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider
2016-04-11 01:56:10.806 DEBUG 17850 --- [nio-9999-exec-7] o.s.s.a.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider    : User 'acme' not found
2016-04-11 01:56:10.806 DEBUG 17850 --- [nio-9999-exec-7] w.a.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter : Authentication request failed: org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException: Bad credentials
2016-04-11 01:56:10.806 DEBUG 17850 --- [nio-9999-exec-7] w.a.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter : Updated SecurityContextHolder to contain null Authentication
2016-04-11 01:56:10.806 DEBUG 17850 --- [nio-9999-exec-7] w.a.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter : Delegating to authentication failure handler org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler@15daee11
2016-04-11 01:56:10.806 DEBUG 17850 --- [nio-9999-exec-7] .a.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler : Redirecting to /login?error
2016-04-11 01:56:10.806 DEBUG 17850 --- [nio-9999-exec-7] o.s.s.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy        : Redirecting to '/uaa/login?error'
2016-04-11 01:56:10.806 DEBUG 17850 --- [nio-9999-exec-7] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
2016-04-11 01:56:10.806 DEBUG 17850 --- [nio-9999-exec-7] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
2016-04-11 01:56:10.824 DEBUG 17850 --- [nio-9999-exec-8] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/css/**']
2016-04-11 01:56:10.824 DEBUG 17850 --- [nio-9999-exec-8] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/login'; against '/css/**'
2016-04-11 01:56:10.824 DEBUG 17850 --- [nio-9999-exec-8] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/js/**']
2016-04-11 01:56:10.824 DEBUG 17850 --- [nio-9999-exec-8] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/login'; against '/js/**'
2016-04-11 01:56:10.824 DEBUG 17850 --- [nio-9999-exec-8] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/images/**']
2016-04-11 01:56:10.824 DEBUG 17850 --- [nio-9999-exec-8] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/login'; against '/images/**'
2016-04-11 01:56:10.824 DEBUG 17850 --- [nio-9999-exec-8] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/**/favicon.ico']
2016-04-11 01:56:10.824 DEBUG 17850 --- [nio-9999-exec-8] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/login'; against '/**/favicon.ico'
2016-04-11 01:56:10.824 DEBUG 17850 --- [nio-9999-exec-8] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/error']
2016-04-11 01:56:10.824 DEBUG 17850 --- [nio-9999-exec-8] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/login'; against '/error'
2016-04-11 01:56:10.824 DEBUG 17850 --- [nio-9999-exec-8] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : No matches found
2016-04-11 01:56:10.824 DEBUG 17850 --- [nio-9999-exec-8] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/login']
2016-04-11 01:56:10.824 DEBUG 17850 --- [nio-9999-exec-8] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/login'; against '/login'
2016-04-11 01:56:10.824 DEBUG 17850 --- [nio-9999-exec-8] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : matched
2016-04-11 01:56:10.824 DEBUG 17850 --- [nio-9999-exec-8] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /login?error at position 1 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
2016-04-11 01:56:10.824 DEBUG 17850 --- [nio-9999-exec-8] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /login?error at position 2 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
2016-04-11 01:56:10.824 DEBUG 17850 --- [nio-9999-exec-8] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : HttpSession returned null object for SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT
2016-04-11 01:56:10.824 DEBUG 17850 --- [nio-9999-exec-8] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade@2f575638. A new one will be created.
2016-04-11 01:56:10.824 DEBUG 17850 --- [nio-9999-exec-8] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /login?error at position 3 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
2016-04-11 01:56:10.824 DEBUG 17850 --- [nio-9999-exec-8] o.s.s.w.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter  : Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@63eea474
2016-04-11 01:56:10.824 DEBUG 17850 --- [nio-9999-exec-8] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /login?error at position 4 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'CsrfFilter'
2016-04-11 01:56:10.824 DEBUG 17850 --- [nio-9999-exec-8] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /login?error at position 5 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
2016-04-11 01:56:10.824 DEBUG 17850 --- [nio-9999-exec-8] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'GET /login' doesn't match 'POST /logout
2016-04-11 01:56:10.824 DEBUG 17850 --- [nio-9999-exec-8] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /login?error at position 6 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter'
2016-04-11 01:56:10.828 DEBUG 17850 --- [nio-9999-exec-8] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'GET /login' doesn't match 'POST /login
2016-04-11 01:56:10.828 DEBUG 17850 --- [nio-9999-exec-8] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /login?error at position 7 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter'
2016-04-11 01:56:10.828 DEBUG 17850 --- [nio-9999-exec-8] o.s.s.w.s.DefaultSavedRequest            : pathInfo: both null (property equals)
2016-04-11 01:56:10.828 DEBUG 17850 --- [nio-9999-exec-8] o.s.s.w.s.DefaultSavedRequest            : queryString: arg1=client_id=acme&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/login&response_type=code&state=q0YqtY; arg2=error (property not equals)
2016-04-11 01:56:10.828 DEBUG 17850 --- [nio-9999-exec-8] o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache        : saved request doesn't match
2016-04-11 01:56:10.828 DEBUG 17850 --- [nio-9999-exec-8] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /login?error at position 8 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
2016-04-11 01:56:10.828 DEBUG 17850 --- [nio-9999-exec-8] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /login?error at position 9 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
2016-04-11 01:56:10.865 DEBUG 17850 --- [nio-9999-exec-8] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Populated SecurityContextHolder with anonymous token: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@905571d8: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@0: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: 49C866D11F4CC5AF4ACDC58145A672BA; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS'
2016-04-11 01:56:10.865 DEBUG 17850 --- [nio-9999-exec-8] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /login?error at position 10 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter'
2016-04-11 01:56:10.865 DEBUG 17850 --- [nio-9999-exec-8] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /login?error at position 11 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
2016-04-11 01:56:10.865 DEBUG 17850 --- [nio-9999-exec-8] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /login?error at position 12 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
2016-04-11 01:56:10.865 DEBUG 17850 --- [nio-9999-exec-8] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /login?error; Attributes: [permitAll]
2016-04-11 01:56:10.865 DEBUG 17850 --- [nio-9999-exec-8] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@905571d8: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@0: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: 49C866D11F4CC5AF4ACDC58145A672BA; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS
2016-04-11 01:56:10.865 DEBUG 17850 --- [nio-9999-exec-8] o.s.s.access.vote.AffirmativeBased       : Voter: org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@5cb57e17, returned: 1
2016-04-11 01:56:10.865 DEBUG 17850 --- [nio-9999-exec-8] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Authorization successful
2016-04-11 01:56:10.865 DEBUG 17850 --- [nio-9999-exec-8] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : RunAsManager did not change Authentication object
2016-04-11 01:56:10.865 DEBUG 17850 --- [nio-9999-exec-8] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /login?error reached end of additional filter chain; proceeding with original chain
2016-04-11 01:56:10.867 DEBUG 17850 --- [nio-9999-exec-8] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
2016-04-11 01:56:10.867 DEBUG 17850 --- [nio-9999-exec-8] o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Chain processed normally
2016-04-11 01:56:10.867 DEBUG 17850 --- [nio-9999-exec-8] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
2016-04-11 01:56:10.958 DEBUG 17850 --- [nio-9999-exec-9] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/css/**']
2016-04-11 01:56:10.958 DEBUG 17850 --- [nio-9999-exec-9] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/css/wro.css'; against '/css/**'
2016-04-11 01:56:10.958 DEBUG 17850 --- [nio-9999-exec-9] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : matched
2016-04-11 01:56:10.958 DEBUG 17850 --- [nio-9999-exec-9] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /css/wro.css has an empty filter list
2016-04-11 01:56:10.959 DEBUG 17850 --- [nio-9999-exec-9] .s.o.p.e.FrameworkEndpointHandlerMapping : Looking up handler method for path /css/wro.css
2016-04-11 01:56:10.959 DEBUG 17850 --- [nio-9999-exec-9] .s.o.p.e.FrameworkEndpointHandlerMapping : Did not find handler method for [/css/wro.css]
2016-04-11 01:56:10.961 DEBUG 17850 --- [io-9999-exec-10] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/css/**']
2016-04-11 01:56:10.961 DEBUG 17850 --- [io-9999-exec-10] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/js/wro.js'; against '/css/**'
2016-04-11 01:56:10.961 DEBUG 17850 --- [io-9999-exec-10] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/js/**']
2016-04-11 01:56:10.961 DEBUG 17850 --- [io-9999-exec-10] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/js/wro.js'; against '/js/**'
2016-04-11 01:56:10.961 DEBUG 17850 --- [io-9999-exec-10] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : matched
2016-04-11 01:56:10.961 DEBUG 17850 --- [io-9999-exec-10] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /js/wro.js has an empty filter list
2016-04-11 01:56:10.962 DEBUG 17850 --- [io-9999-exec-10] .s.o.p.e.FrameworkEndpointHandlerMapping : Looking up handler method for path /js/wro.js
2016-04-11 01:56:10.962 DEBUG 17850 --- [io-9999-exec-10] .s.o.p.e.FrameworkEndpointHandlerMapping : Did not find handler method for [/js/wro.js]
```

Alternatively, giving the credentials `user` and `password`, as per `application.properties`, results in a redirect to `localhost:9000/uaa` with an xml error message which states that `you must be fully authenticated to view this resource`.

Comment: acme / acmesecret are client credentials, you can't login with them.

Comment: @DirkLachowski So then what credentials do I use to log in?

Comment: login: user  password:password as in the application.properties

Comment: @RafaelZeffa OK.  Please note the last paragraph at the end of the OP reporting the reject message I got yesterday when using those credentials.  I tried it again just now per your suggestion, and now it is working.  What explains the change?  The apps are the same today as yesterday, except perhaps a couple breakpoints.  The only environmental change is that the computer was asleep for 15 hours.  Why would it work now but not yesterday?